# How to apt pin a future package from next version of ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, beta, pinning

(Note: I understand I may need additional packages that have dependencies, and can work that out on my own, do not worry that I am asking about a single package).

I have Ubuntu Mate Disco Dingo (19.04) which retrieves the package version 6.0.6 for package virtualbox : https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/virtualbox

Due to a bug that affects me in 6.06 that is corrected in 6.08, (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog - User interface: fix mouse click pass-through problems in multi-screen virtual machines (6.0.6 regression, bug #18567)) I require the ability to upgrade to the next version of virtualbox, that is available in Ubuntu Eoan (https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/virtualbox).

I am not able to use the repo provided by virtualbox directly, as this repo lacks another package I require due to running ubuntu under a secure boot configuration, that has been configured with certificates already to load the signed dkms module on boot. I have tested this solution path already and it renders virtualbox unusable.

As a result, I would like the ability to apt pin just the packages I need from the next version of Ubuntu (Eoan) that is not yet released and is in alpha.

I have not had to apt pin before and so would appreciate any advice on how to apt pin a future version of the repos, with just the specific packages I need (virtualbox being the example) so that I can upgrade my virtualbox to the patched version. As I mention, once I know how to do a single package, I will obviously be able to sort out any dependencies on my own.

Thanking you in advance :)
Pete

(If I am not clear about anything, please let me know and I will attempt to clarify what I need to do :)

Comment: This thread shows how to hold back a single package, while all others are upgraded. I am asking the opposite, to hold back all packages to the current distribution repo, while allowing one package to be upgraded from a future repo.

Comment: I VTCed as off-topic because it is about using a package from a development release, which IMO should not be supported here for the same reason we don't support development releases in the first place.

Comment: Well thanks for nothing everyone who voted. Guess I will go somewhere else to ask my question and abandon askubuntu.

Comment: I figured out how to do it on my own by going to a different forum. Works fine.